# Is average kinetic energy equal to the total thermal energy of a gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature, ideal-gas

"Average KE" as in this equation:

$$K_{average} = \frac{3}{2} kT$$

Since potential energy in ideal gas model is eliminated, I guess  this equation is also for the total thermal energy of a gas/a system.

Also, is it just for a single gas molecule? 
Is there a simple algebraic derivation for the equation? (Just provide the source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Thermal energy" is a bit of a misnomer because "thermal" really refers to a method of energy *transfer*, not energy *storage*. When energy moves from one system to another, it can do so via a thermal process (e.g. conduction, convection, radiation) or a mechanical process (something pushes on something else). So technically, I wouldn't call $\frac{3}{2}kT$ the thermal energy, but rather the *internal energy per particle*.

Nevertheless, $\frac{3}{2}kT$ *is* equal to the average kinetic energy per particle, for an ideal gas whose particles have no relevant dynamics other than translation. (I.e. they can only move, but not rotate, vibrate, change shape, or interact.) You can prove it by first calculating the entropy of an ideal gas, as shown in the [Wikipedia article on the Gibbs paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox). In the derivation, the internal energy $U$ is taken to be equal to the kinetic energy. The entropy depends on $U$ in the form $S = kN\ln U^{3/2} + \cdots$, so you can then take the derivative and set it equal to $1/T$:
$$\frac{1}{T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial U} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{kN}{U}$$
This is easily rearranged to $U = \frac{3}{2}NkT$, and the energy per particle is $U/N = \frac{3}{2}kT$ as expected.

Comment: Is thermal energy (microscopic KE and PE) simply the hotness of something?

Comment: Is temperature a indicator of the thermal energy of two EQUAL SIZED objects?

Comment: Size has nothing to do with it. And actually, temperature in general is not an indicator of thermal energy, only of the tendency to transfer energy.

Comment: But a icy cold iceberg has more thermal energy than a cup of hot boiling water?

Comment: Assuming by thermal energy you mean internal energy in the sense I used it in the answer: yes, an iceberg has more internal energy than a cup of boiling water.

Comment: Then thermal energy = internal energy = microscopic KE + PE? Btw, when do you know thermal energy is internal energy?

Comment: Perhaps best to check [Wikipedia on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy).

Comment: Could you give the general intuition how the formula can calculate the average kinetic energy of each gas particle without knowing how many there are?

Comment: I didn't learn derivative yet.

Comment: I am assuming at a set temperature, the KE is constant. So the more particles, the less the average KE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26630/discussion-between-david-z-and-user132522).

Comment: @DavidZ you mentioned that for an assumed ideal gas that, other than translation, there are no dynamics such as rotation or vibration. But real gas molecules do vibrate and some have more or different modes than others depending on shape, etc. So would water (vapor) molecules for example carry more energy than nitrogen molecules? At the same temperature do they carry more heat?